# Facebook profile photo, how to make it the actual size with javascript

Tags: facebook

So I want to make a facebook profile photo its actual size:

https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-snc6/179672_10151462004583896_870987263_n.jpg 
here's the photo.

I know that you can insert java script somewhere to make it this way, but I don't know what the javascript IS nor do I know where to put it on facebook.

Help

Thank you!

Comment: You can add JavaScript in a FaceBook input???

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean on your webpage?

```
var Img = document.getElementById('ImgId');
if(Img && Img.style) {
Img.style.height = '200px';
Img.style.width = '100px';
}
```

If you just want to resize you can use paint, photoshop or online services like picresize and cutmypic!!

Comment: I don't want to resize the photo. Facebook profile photo uploader makes it so that your picture only fits a certain dimension. I want it to fit the dimension I already have it in, the picture that I posted.